# How to open a huge(10GB) binary file in python in the original data structure?

Tags: python, scipy, binaryfiles

I am trying to open a 10GB binary file using **`IDL.readsav`**, since it was created using IDL. It leads to Memoryerror.

Is there any other general way to retrieve the original data structure (Tables/array) from the binary file?

Comment: What does "IDL.readsav" mean?

Comment: I suppose you have Memoryerro because you don't have enough RAM.
In general, you need to parse such files by blocks.

Comment: from scipy.io.idl import readsav. It is use to open idl .sav files.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file

Comment: There's not just one "binary file" format, and the details of how one indexes and into and reads such a format are typically part of that format's design (if it's intended for fast random-access -- such is the case with pretty much anything intended to be used as a database; doubly so if it's intended to support in-place edits that change data lengths, as that kind of support means your binary file format needs to have its own chunking, allocation and lookup logic -- this is part of what databases do).